# Generate Signed Apk Error Multidex

Tags: android, apk

My app is working properly. There is no problem. i want to build generated signed apk. The problem is building take too long and completed with errors.
Please check the image. Thanks.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

here my gradle;

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "umut.com.anyidea"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}


dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.6.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image: image of errors]

Comment: Show the entire stacktrace here, don't post photos.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In versions of Google Play services prior to 6.5, you had to compile the entire package of APIs into your app. In some cases, doing so made it more difficult to keep the number of methods in your app (including framework APIs, library methods, and your own code) under the 65,536 limit.

From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play service APIs into your app. For example, to include only the Google Fit and Android Wear APIs,

Please refer this document: 
  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

for example if you need Google Account Login then just use : 
  com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1 not use compile   'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'

Comment: i update my library to 9.6.1 and problem solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just add this and try.
its works for me.

```
 defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    // multidex issues
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

**or**

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you add this in `Application` class

```
MultiDex.install(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in defaultConfig block

> multiDexEnabled true

And add the following dependencies

> compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

After this rebuild your project. Hopefully this should resolve your error.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove unused libraries (or dependencies) from app's build.gradle file and again try to  generate signed apk. It will work. :)

Comment: What If there is no unused library/dependency is there?